# given distances to 3 known points 2d, find the 4th point

Tags: geometry

Lets say you have three points in $2D$, which are non-collinear: $a$, $b$ and $c$.

How can you find a $4$th point, when you have the distance from the $4$th point to $a$, $b$ and $c$ ?

Comment: The formula for distance is [(x-x1)^2+(y-y1)^2+(z-z1)^2]^(1/2). Just plug in your known points and you have three linear equations in three variables.

Comment: Is the fourth point to be in the same plane as the other three?  Then for almost all combinations $(d_1,d_2,d_3)$ of distances, there will not be such a fourth point.

Answer (score 1):

For each point a,b,c, draw a circle with center at that point, having a radius equal to its distance to 4th point. The 4th point is where all circles intersect.